# Salesforce SSO setup with ADFS for specific User groups in AD

Tags: active-directory, salesforce, single-sign-on, adfs, adfs3.0

So here is my dilemma or my somewhat up in the air question .

I have set my self with with a scenario in such that I've enabled SSO on Salesforce using ADFS certs, but currently all users have access to go through salesforce using SSO. I'd like to limit SSO to only three groups "user groups defined in AD" to be the only ones to be able to use SSO in salesforce.

I know i need to delegate access but not sure if i need to do this on the ADFS side or the salesforce end.... on ADFS the only thing i've done is create the certificate and brought them in salesforce and then taken the XML generated and bring that into ADFS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it .

After Searching the web and this form i came to realise that there is a Delegated Authentication and i might need to install a Delegated Authentication WSDL not sure if this step is necessary for ADFS 3.0 .

Many people seem to point to using Delegated Authentication , but i'm wondering if there is any way to get the same functionality using claim tickets on the adfs server.

Thank You Again :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems like a better question for [server fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to describe something doable via AD FS authorization rules. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/when-to-use-an-authorization-claim-rule

Essentially what you do is on the relying party for Salesforce in AD FS, you create authorization rules to permit/deny based on AD group membership. Therefore, if user is in group, AD FS issues token. if not, they get a deny which means no token that would allow access to Salesforce.

Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/access-control-policies-in-ad-fs because based on your AD FS version you may be able to do this via an access control policy instead of issuance authorization rules.

Comment: Awesome, i will take a look into Authorization Rules right now :) , have you ever created Authorization rules before  ?

Comment: Thank you :) , any chance you'd be able to post a screen shot of a random group you've used to implement the Auth rules, i read into it but unfortunately dont have a lab ready with ADFS installed at the moment :( and my curiosity is killing me LOL , really appreciate the reply !!!!! means a lot and the links you provided were awesome !!!!

Comment: well if your curiosity is killing you, then setting up a lab in Azure for free and using a salesforce development tenant for free to play around with might be exactly what you need to do :)

Comment: so i took your advise regarding the Auth Rules :) , i'm stuck however on one section when making the claim rule 

I fill out the fields as follows in Add Transform Claim Rule Wizard , in ADFS Mgmt 

Claim Rule Name : Sales_Force_Test

User's Group : "I Choose my AD users group" via browse 

Outgoing Claim Type: // Here im a bit lost so i select "NAME ID" 

Outgoing name ID Format : UPN 

Outgoing claim value : NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE LOL , its not letting me finish the wizard without this field instated. 

Any help would be great  :)

Comment: Sorry for the formatting , for some reason i cant attach images or format my text properly when posting on stack overflow